# send sensor's raw data using network socket on Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sensors

I'm trying to make an app that reads sensor (gyroscope) raw data and send it, on real-time, to other device using socket.
I've already implemented a simple communication between the two sides by using  Java Socket class inside an AsyncTask and it works fine with dummy data.

I'm not sure how should I integrate the whole reading raw data from sensor part with the socket part.

A button click should triger the start of sensor read and from that moment, in every 10ms a sample should be made and the sampled data should be sent via the socket.

Should I use another asyncTask for reading data from sensor? How can I send the data sampled from the sensor to the socket's AsyncTask while it executed? What is the best practise in this sutuation?

Here's the code I already hava (only socket handling, no sensor)
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnConnect, btnCloseSocket;
EditText etIP;
EditText etPort;
boolean isConnected = false;
ConnectToServerAsyncTask connectToServerAsyncTask = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    btnCloseSocket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_closeSocket);
}

public void socketOperationRequest(View view) {

    if (!isConnected) {
        connectToServerAsyncTask = new ConnectToServerAsyncTask(MainActivity.this);
    }
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_connect:
        {
            isConnected = true;
            etIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
            etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_port);
            String IP = etIP.getText().toString();
            String port = etPort.getText().toString();
            connectToServerAsyncTask.execute(IP, port);
            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
            btnCloseSocket.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn_closeSocket:
        {
            isConnected = false;
            connectToServerAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            btnCloseSocket.setEnabled(false);
            btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

AsyncTask:

```
public class ConnectToServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

Context context;
Socket socket;
OutputStream os;
//boolean running = true;

public ConnectToServerAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String IP = strings[0];
    String port = strings[1];
    InputStream is = null;
    int data = 1;
    try {
        InetAddress inetIP = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        socket = new Socket(inetIP, Integer.parseInt(port));
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        publishProgress("test");
        while(!this.isCancelled()){
            os.write(data);
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        publishProgress("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        publishProgress("Exception2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    String message = values[0];
    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    try {
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for my bad English,
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you already have.

Comment: @Nulano edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should find your sensor in the `SensorManager`. For example (replace your `os.write` loop with this, then add an infinite sleep loop like you have):

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor gyro = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
sensorManager.registerListener(new MySensorListener(), gyro, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Then you should implement the listener, to write to the os from it's `onSensorChanged` methods.

Make sure to unregister that listener (`unregisterListener`) before you close your stream.

For more information see the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: thank you. Where should I implement the listener? In my current AsyncTask?

Comment: @Noam Sure, that will work. You just have to make sure it has access to the OutputStream, but you can just pass that in through it's constructor.